# Complex ordering of Active Record Collection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an Active Record collection of games that includes base games and board games.

```
# All Games (Base Games and Expansions)
games = current_user.games
```

I have a filter method that filters the games based on different parameters. However, I'd like to move the expansions next to the base game in the collection. How would I go about doing that. I can get the base games and expansions by doing:

```
# Base Games
games.where(game_type: 'boardgame')

# Expansions
games.where(game_type: 'boardgameexpansion')
```

An expansion can technically have multiple parents, so you can get to the first parent game by doing just that:

```
my_game.parents.first
```

**How can I locate the parent game in the `games` collection, and move the expansion next to it?** Even though an expansion can have multiple parents, I'll assume the first parent is always okay to move to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these collections are loaded into memory, some array manipulation should do the job:

```
expansions = games.includes(:parents).where(game_type: 'boardgameexpansion')
ordered_games = games.where(game_type: 'boardgame').to_a

expansions.find_each do |expansion|
  parent = expansion.parents.first
  parent_idx = ordered_games.index(parent)
  if parent_idx.nil?
    # no parent, can this happen? just add it to the end of the list
    ordered_games << expansion
  else
    # place the expansion immediatel after the parent
    ordered_games.insert(parent_idx + 1, expansion)
  end
end
```

Performance would not be great on a large dataset, but this simple option may suit you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was having difficulty trying to put that together in my head. This looks really useful and I'll try to implement it soon.